# Gasless Send: Keeping of Ether Wrongfully

Tags: vulnerability

I got following code from:
[A survey of Attacks from Ethereum Smart Contracts](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1007.pdf)

```
contract C { 
 function pay(uint n, address d){ 
    d.send(n);  
 } 
}
contract D1 {
  uint public count = 0;
  function(){ 
   count++; 
  }

}
```

One article at:
[Contract Fuzzer: Fuzzing Smart Contracts....](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1807/1807.03932.pdf)
says that:

> If such exception is not checked and propagated appropriately, a
>   malicious sender can keep ether wrongfully while seemingly innocent.

For send gas stipend is 2300. So if send fails due to costly fall back function control would come back to 'contract C'. Exception is not propagated in case of 'send'. 'send' returns false. Can some body please guide me "how a malicious sender can keep Ether wrongfully in this case?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody calls function `pay` of a `C` instance with the address of a `D1` instance:

- The `C` instance is supposed to send `n` wei to the `D1` instance
- As a result of `d.send`, the fallback function of the `D1` instance will be executed
- This function changes a state-variable of the `D1` instance, an operation which costs at least 5000 gas
- Since this is more than the 2300 gas stipend, the fallback function will revert due to insufficient gas
- The `C` instance will keep those `n` wei to itself, even though it was supposed to give them away

Comment: So the owner of the contract C or the miner can keep those n wei.

Comment: @zak100: The miner has nothing to do with that. He or she will just get a (rather small) gas fee in this case, regardless of the final outcome. But the contract `C` instance will keep the funds that it was supposed to send to the contract `D1` instance.